# Partition by when NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that looks like

```
Year  Month  ID     Date     Status
--------------------------------------
2013    8   99999   8/1/2013 Status A
2013    9   99999   NULL     NULL
2013    10  99999   NULL     NULL
2013    11  99999   NULL     NULL
2013    12  99999   NULL     NULL
2014    1   99999   NULL     NULL
2014    2   99999   2/5/2014 Status B
2014    3   99999   NULL     NULL
2014    4   99999   NULL     NULL
2014    5   99999   NULL     NULL
2014    6   99999   NULL     NULL
2014    7   99999   NULL     NULL
```

I want to add a column that will give me the number of the status, repeated until the next occurrence of a status, where it will add 1.

Result:

```
Year  Month  ID     Date     Status   Value
--------------------------------------------
2013    8   99999   8/1/2013 Status A 1
2013    9   99999   NULL     NULL     1
2013    10  99999   NULL     NULL     1
2013    11  99999   NULL     NULL     1
2013    12  99999   NULL     NULL     1
2014    1   99999   NULL     NULL     1
2014    2   99999   2/5/2014 Status B 2
2014    3   99999   NULL     NULL     2
2014    4   99999   NULL     NULL     2
2014    5   99999   NULL     NULL     2
2014    6   99999   NULL     NULL     2
2014    7   99999   NULL     NULL     2
```

The Nulls are whats throwing me off...Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Here's my current query:

```
DECLARE @DateStart DATETIME
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME

SET @DateStart = '8/1/2013'
SET @DateEnd = '7/1/2014'

SELECT    
   P.Year, P.Month, P.ID,
   PP.MaxStatusDate,
   Status
FROM      
    (SELECT    
        *
     FROM      
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            year, Month 
         FROM      
            lu_Calendar
         WHERE     
            Date BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd) AS A
     CROSS JOIN 
         (SELECT DISTINCT
             ID
          FROM   
             dbo.StatusChangeData) AS B
    ) AS P
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  
        yr, mnth, MaxStatusDate, Status, A.ID
     FROM    
        (SELECT    
            ID, YEAR([ModifiedDate]) AS yr,
            MONTH(ModifiedDate) AS mnth,
            MAX([ModifiedDate]) AS MaxStatusDate
        FROM      
            dbo.StatusChangeData
        GROUP BY  
            ID, YEAR([ModifiedDate]), MONTH(ModifiedDate)) AS A
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.StatusChangeData sce ON sce.ID = A.ID AND A.MaxStatusDate = sce.[ModifiedDate]
) AS PP ON P.Month = pp.mnth AND P.YEAR = PP.yr AND P.ID = PP.ID
WHERE     
    P.ID = 99999
```

Comment: Could you please post your current query?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  Essentially, this counts the number of not-`NULL` values before any given value:

```
select scd.*,
       (select count(*)
        from StatusChangeData scd2
        where scd2.id = scd.id and
              scd2.status is not null and
              scd2.year*100+scd2.month <= scd.year*100+scd.month
       ) as value
from StatusChangeData scd;
```

Comment: This causes 'value' to turn to 2 when the new year starts, but if you'll notice, the status changes in Feb of 2014, so that's when the next number needs to occur. It can not rely on the year or month, as those are parameters that may change.

Comment: @Pops . . . I see now what you are saying.  There was a typo in the comparison.  The year and month from `scd2` should be compared to the year and month from `scd`, and the expression is now fixed.